# SOQL to query Custom Labels in Salesforce

Tags: soql, workbench, customlabel

Can anyone suggest me the SOQL which can export custom labels in Salesforce along with its translated texts?

Comment: Labels cannot be queried via normal SOQL, you have to use Metadata to achieve this if you are writing this in APEX: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi. Or if you are in Developer console just check the option "Use Tooling API"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You can use SOQL Tooling api - can test from developer console:**

[image]
[image]

**Also in older orgs you have objects ExternalString and ExternalStringLocalization which will give info on custom labels and also translated labels.**

[image]
[image]