# categories from customLabels, in SOQL

Tags: soql, customlabel, categories

I need to find the categories in my labels. So,

Starting from 
[SOQL to query Custom Labels in Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282077/soql-to-query-custom-labels-in-salesforce)

and the documentation
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customlabels.htm#!

I torn on tooling, and try this query:

```
Select Id, Name, ManageableState, NamespacePrefix, value FROM CustomLabel where NamespacePrefix = null
```

It works, and i get the expected results, as we are already using lots of labels in visualforce. But now i need also the cateories, associated with those labels. So i try:

```
Select Id, Name, ManageableState, NamespacePrefix, value, categories FROM CustomLabel where NamespacePrefix = null
```

and i get:

> No such column 'categories' on entity 'ExternalString'. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after
>   the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call
>   for the appropriate names.

But it's right there in documentation!

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `ExternalString` table which represents a custom label for a translatable UI component. Includes access to the associated label in the Metadata API. Available in API version 38.0 and later as per [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_externalstring.htm)

```
select Id,
    Name,
    ManageableState,
    NamespacePrefix,
    Value,
    Category
from ExternalString
where NamespacePrefix = null
```

Comment: computer said no:
sObject type 'ExternalString' is not supported.

Comment: Are you using Tooling API?

Comment: Yes, checking that box enables the query: Thanks!. Is there a way to also get the translations?